# Working Molehill 2D Engine

Tags: actionscript-3, 2d, molehill, flash-player-11

Where can I get working engine for Molehill 2D?

I checked ND2D and M2D and none of them work on Flash Player 11.
Not even the Demos.

Are there any working examples, or tutorials?

Comment: I've been using ND2D to develop a number of applications. It works fine in FP11 and AIR 3.0 for me (tested across Windows and Mac, major browser versions). Can you describe your problem in more detail? Have you confirmed you are running 11 in your browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about the [Starling Framework](http://www.bytearray.org/?p=3371) ?

Comment: Odd on my work computer I can't get the demos to work from that site.

Comment: Odd indeed. What Flash Player version are you using ? How about platform and browser ? I'm using Flash Player 11.0.1.152 on osx 10.6.8 with Safari 5.0.5. Do you get any errors at all ?

Comment: flash player is 10.2.152 on FireFox windows xp no errors just a white box that pops up and poofs in a millisecond then all is black

Comment: Flash Player 10.2 is not the same as as Flash Player 11. You do understand the Molehill means Flash Player 11 only,right ? Try to upgrade your Flash Player to 11 as it's been officially released and there are debug versions as well and visit the demos again.

Comment: Levan, glad to help! Feel free to vote/mark acceptable answers ;) Welcome to stackoverflow !

Answer (score 0):

It seems that something is wrong with your setup. I'm developing using ND2D and it works fine at all my PCs in external player and in browser.